# How to verify gpg key in a packer template

Tags: packer

I have a packer json template which includes

```
"type": "shell",
    "inline": [
      "sudo wget https://694911143906-eu-west-1-guardduty-agent-rpm-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/1.0.0/x86_64/amazon-guardduty-agent-1.0.0.x86_64.rpm",
      "sudo wget https://694911143906-eu-west-1-guardduty-agent-rpm-artifacts.s3.aws.com/1.0.0/x86_64/amazon-guardduty-agent-1.0.0.x86_64.sig",
      "sudo wget https://694911143906-eu-west-1-guardduty-agent-rpm-artifacts.s3.amazonaws.com/1.0.0/publickey.pem",
      "sudo gpg --import publickey.pem",
      "sudo gpg --verify amazon-guardduty-agent-1.0.0.x86_64.sig amazon-guardduty-agent-1.0.0.x86_64.rpm",
      "sudo rpm -ivh amazon-guardduty-agent-1.0.0.x86_64.rpm"
    ]
  }
```

This installs AWS ec2-runtime security agent in the ami. Is there a way to *stop/error out* if the gpg verify fails?

Comment: Are you noticing that different behavior occurs?

Comment: doh, you're right, it does error out by itself.